# Python selenium find_element_by_xpath not finding existing element in page

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am using Python 3.6+ and Selenium 3.141

I am trying to get an element from a page, and although I'm using the correct Xpath expression (confirmed in the brower console), the same Xpath expression raises a 'NotFound' error in selenium chrome driver.

### myscript.py

```
from selenium import webdriver


url = 'https://live.euronext.com/en/product/stock-options/AH1-DPAR'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
browser.get(url)

try:
    
    checkbox = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form-options-index"]/div/div[2]')
    
except:
    pass
```

The script throws an exception where the `find_element_by_xpath()` method is invoked - even though when using a browser, the same Xpath expression will result in the element being identified/selected correctly.

Why is the Xpath expression not working with selenium? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required content absent in page source - it's loaded dynamically, so you need to wait until it appear in DOM:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://live.euronext.com/en/product/stock-options/AH1-DPAR'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
browser.get(url)

checkbox = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="form-options-index"]/div/div[2]')))
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on `Select all` CheckBox. Use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `Xpath`.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="form-options-index"]//label[@for="select_all_dates"]'))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```